# Dynamic loop unexpectedly stops in CDF Player Pro V11.3

Tags: dynamic, infinite-loop

**Correction**
The issue described below it is not caused by CDF Player Pro after all. Apologies for the confusion. The Dynamic loop just unexpectedly stops anyways (it just takes longer when run in Mathematica rather than in Player Pro).
Question title should be modified to: "**Dynamic loop unexpectedly stops**".
(sorry I do not know how to do that)

**Content:**
- The issue
- Details

**The issue**
I have created a dynamic loop in Mathematica V11.1. When I run the notebook or CDF document, said loop unexpectedly stops. I simplified the original code by reducing it to a trivial loop (please see below) ... there must be some incorrect logic implemented there.

**Details**
I found that the time taken for the below mentioned loop to stop is not constant.
Example (approx values in seconds):
run in M V11.1.1 --> {5, 5032, 1060, 446, 2530, 2416}
run in CDF Player Pro --> {249, 222, 292, 2011, 1370}

No error message is returned, I also did not notice any "anomalies" in "Windows Event Viewer".

Once the loop stops I re-launch it following these steps:
- Disable Dynamic Update
- Quit Local Kernel
- Evaluate Notebook
- Enable Dynamic Update

I also tried (without success) the following:
- running the loop from within a package that I created
- wrapping the dynamic loop around Manipulate

What did I do wrong?
Does anyone have any suggestion on how to solve this issue?
Thanks again.

```
Framed[
DynamicModule[
{samplingPeriod = 5, process, output, adesso, timeInit, timeInitRel,
deltaT, deltaTRel, draw, count = 0},
Column[{
 (*--- Outer time loop ---*)
 Dynamic[
     count++;
     deltaT = DateDifference[DateObject[timeInit], DateObject[Now],"Second"];
     deltaTRel = Quantity[count, "Second"];
     Grid[{{"Time", "Abs Duration", "Rel Duration"}, {DateString[Now],
     deltaT, deltaTRel}}]
 , UpdateInterval -> 1, SynchronousUpdating -> True, 
 TrackedSymbols -> {}]
,
(*--- Computational loop ---*)
Dynamic[
 (*--- Simple process ---*)
 draw = RandomReal[];
 (*-- Time stamp of the simple process ---*)
 adesso = DateString[Now];

 output = Column[{
    Row[{"Last Sampling time: ", adesso}],
    Row[{"Draw: ", draw}]
    }];
 Panel[output]
 , UpdateInterval -> samplingPeriod, SynchronousUpdating -> False,
  TrackedSymbols -> {}]
}],
Initialization :> (
(*--- Initate time loop ---*)
timeInit = Now;
)]]
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for Wolfram's support

Comment: I actually did contact Wolfram's support. They are not aware of such issue. They said most probably it is due to the OS. But I am in no position to test in multiple machines/OS CDF-Player Pro. Hence my post.

Comment: They didn't investigate to help you figure out the issue? Did they look at your code?

Comment: Not sure if they did. My email did contain the code (very similar to the one I posted) ... but that was it. No suggestions on how to solve this issue.

Comment: are you sure that the code when running in Mathematica will indeed not stop? I find it hard to believe that this should behave differently for Mathematica and the Player, which I so far have never seen (but which of course is not impossible). One thing that immediatly sticks out are the useless `Dynamic` wrappers for `adesso`, `draw` and `output`: as all three are never changed all of them will not help but potentially could cause some timing issues during updates. So what I would suggest is to remove those and see whether that will make the code work as intended.

Comment: @Albert Retey: thank you very much for your reply and suggestion. Really appreciated. After removing the useless Dynamic wrappers the problem persists. The "duration" value displayed in four tests without Dynamic wrappers are approximately: {262, 624, 789, 1484}. In M I never experienced an interruption in the loop. I find it impossible to believe the difference in behavior between M and Player Pro hence my frustration ... if only one other person could run this trivial loop with Player pro on their W10 machine and replicate this "impossibility", well, that would be a huge help. Thank you all.

Comment: @Guaro: I actually did run this with the CDF Player on my W10 machine and it worked alright (at least up to about 1500, I will start one more try right now). I would rather expect the problem to be related to the two different machines. Have you tried to install the free CDF Player on your local machine and tried whether it works there?

Comment: One more thing: While it is an interesting thing to play with I don't think that using the `Dynamic` functionality as a way to control program execution as in your example is such a good idea. The problem is that the update mechanism for `Dynamics` is difficult to control, e.g. when a `Dynamic` is not shown, it will not update. I think it probably would be better to do the actual computations with a `ScheduledTask` and only use `Dynamic` to display the results. I even would think that the problems you see might somehow be related to this use of `Dynamic`...

Comment: one more question: which version of the player are you using, is that also 11.1?

Comment: @AlbertRetey You were correct. Not a CDF Player Pro issue (for the record V11.3). And thanks again, I will definitely look into ScheduledTask ...not understanding the unexpected Dynamic behavior is annoying though.

Comment: I was now running your code - without the extra `Dynamics` - and it stopped working after 21117.1 sec on Windows 10, CDF-Player 11.1. No idea why, though...

Comment: Thank you Albert. We now have at least one more such case. Hopefully we can start to gather some momentum towards solving this matter.